# How to capture all the items inside a control?

Tags: c#

Suppose there is a picturexox on the panel
and there is a datagridview on the picturebox.

I use the following code to capture the panel:

```
System.Drawing.Bitmap bmp = new System.Drawing.Bitmap(panel1.ClientRectangle.Width, panel1.ClientRectangle.Height);
panel1.DrawToBitmap(bmp, panel1.ClientRectangle);
bmp.Save(@"test.jpg");
```

But it seems that only the picturebox has been captured, the datagridview on it is missing.

How can capture the picturebox together with the datagridview?

Comment: Check the controls hierarchy to see if the `DataGridView` is actual a child within the `Panel`.

Comment: or `dataGrid1.Parent.DrawToBitmap` and crop

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `DrawToBitmap` method will capture the graphics drawn in the `Paint` event and all nested controls. If one is missing it isn't nested either directly of indirectly. Here is how this probably happened:

The designer behaviour of `Panels` and `PictureBoxes` is **different**.

`Panels`, like `GroupBoxes`, `TabPages` and a few more are **container controls**.

This means that any control you drag onto them with your **mouse** gets **nested** in them.

`PictureBox` is **not a Container**, like, say a `Button` or a `Label`..

To **nest** your `DataGridView` in the `PictureBox` you have a choice of

- moving it there with the **keyboard (!)**
- nesting it in code ( `yourDGV.Parent = yourPBox1;`)

Do test the success of the keyboard way by moving the `PictureBox` to see if the `DGV` moves with it..

**Update:**

- If you nest the `DGV` in the `PictureBox`, which itself is nested in the `Panel`, all will be well and the result will looks just like what you see.
- However, if you nest **both** `DGV` and `PictureBox` in the `Panel` and merely let them overlap, a strange bug will appear: **Multiple overlapping controls** are drawn in **reverse**, See [here for a post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41330582/panel-objects-order-after-drawtobitmap) and a link about this issue, which is [documented](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.control.drawtobitmap%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)

> Controls inside containers are rendered in reverse order.

but obviously still a bug.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I am wondering what does "moving it there with the keyboard (!)" mean?

Comment: I found dataGridView1.Parent = pictureBox1; will work, but dataGridView1.Parent = panel1; not

Comment: Moving with the keyboard means just that: using the cursor keys (instead of the mouse) to move the selected control will indeed nest a control in a non-container.

Comment: `dataGridView1.Parent = panel1` can only work if  the DGV then is also visible and not covered by the PictureBox.. __BUT__: Note that __multiple overlapping controls__ are drawn in __reverse__, so that is probably why it doesn't work even though it is visibly over the PBox. See [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41330582/panel-objects-order-after-drawtobitmap)!

Comment: Nice workaround: Set B.Parent = A. Where Control B is on top of Control A. This will Keep B visible as it should!