# How to save PictureBox and TextBox in one image?

Tags: c#, winforms

Hi would like to record all my properties (pictureBox1 + pictureBox2 + ...+Textbox2) in one image.

```
private void button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
  try
  {
    if (pictureBox1.Image != null)
    {
      string nom = textBox1.Text;
      string filename = string.Format(@"c:\\Users\\9408054W\\Documents\\QrCodeGenerator\\BadgeQRCode{0}.png", nom);
      pictureBox1.Image.Save(filename);
      button2.Text = "QRCode sauvegardé.";
      button2.BackColor = Color.Green;
    }
  }
  catch (Exception)
  {
    MessageBox.Show("Une erreur est survenue lors de la sauvegarde." +
                    "Check the file permissions.");
    button2.BackColor = Color.Red;
  }
}
```

[image: things to save]

[image: picture final]

Comment: Well then, you need to come up with a storage format that is capable of storing a mix of text and images, that is capable of being written to and read from (and likely be versioned).  Then just write the read and write code.  One solution may be a simple Zip file.  Take a look at `System.IO.Packaging`

Comment: You have to create a bitmap, create a Graphics object from that bitmap, and then draw the image and the text into that bitmap using the Graphic tools.  Save the bitmap.

Comment: Look up [DrawToBitmap](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41865313/how-to-capture-all-the-items-inside-a-control/41873172?r=SearchResults&s=12|25.7271#41873172)

Answer (score 0):

You can give all the control in one `panel` control. And on `Button_Click` event,you can get the height and width of the `panel` control and save it as image.

**Winform Design**

[image]

**Button Click Event**

```
private void btnSaveImage_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
   int width = panel.Size.Width;
   int height = panel.Size.Height;

   Bitmap bm = new Bitmap(width, height);
   panel.DrawToBitmap(bm, new Rectangle(0, 0, width, height));

   bm.Save(@"D:\TestDrawToBitmap.png", ImageFormat.Png);
}
```

**Image Saved**

[image]

Comment: Thanks, but what is panel ?
How can i select all my elements please ?

Comment: panel is a `panel` control. You can drag and drop `panel` from Toolbox.  https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/winforms/controls/panel-control-windows-forms